# how to access properties of document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am  trying to check whether the a css class is used inside the DOM or not. So, I have

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
```

When I print x out, I get a [object NodeList] for classes that exist on the page and classes that dont. Is there a property of x that I can access ? Like the tag name or something. Would be great if somebody can tell me the different properties of x and the ways I can access them.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that  it's plural:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
                           ^
```

You need to iterate over `x` to get the individual elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var element = x[i];

  console.log(element);
}
```

Make sure to add fallback support for Internet Exploder: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Comment: Or if you already know that you only have one element with that class: `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0]` or consider using an Id. Note that `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in IE 8 and under

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check for the presence of a class in the document, you can also use  `querySelector`.

```
var x = document.querySelector('.classname');
```

It returns `null` if no elements have that class, otherwise the first element with that class name. If you want all elements using `classname`:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
```

Now `x` is `null` if the class is not used in the document, otherwise a `Nodelist`, containing all elements with class `classname`, which can be iterated the way [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) showed. In that iteration you can, for example, retrieve the elements `tagName` or its id. Like:

```
for (var i=0;i<x.lenght;(i=i+1)){
   console.log(x[i].id + ': ' + x[i].tagName);
}
```

`document.querySelector` is available in all modern browsers, and for IE version 8 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I almost always use `document.querySelector` (which: *"Returns the first element within the document that matches the specified group of selectors"*), which returns an element object and it's.

I don't know why but in my Chrome's console I write:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image__pic');
img[0]...
```

`img[0]`, despite its happy existance, it doesn't generate any further attributes/methods to use in the completion window. Like there were none (even though I could use *img[0].src* for instance)

On the other hand:

```
var imgq = document.querySelector('.image__pic')
```

Gives me very useful autocompletion on the Console:

[image]

As far as its browser support [it is phenomenal](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector):

[image]

It is also less tricky to use, because `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is a little beast of its own.

Another plus for `querySelector` is its versatility: any kind of CSS selector goes!

On the negative side, [`querySelector` is a bit slower](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector), but I think it's worth it.